# Infix to postfix notation with negative numbers? Code

Tags: java

Hello everyone I am trying to make a calculator for a university project with infix to postfix notation, now the problem I have is when I try to introduce negative numbers, and I'll be honest I'm very stressed and I really don't understand several posts that I saw, I did not understand any, I need at least a portion of code to understand, here is my code:

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class InfixPostfixEvaluator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InfixPostfixEvaluator infix = new InfixPostfixEvaluator();
        String a = "(342 / 2)";
        String cad = infix.postfixConversion(a);
        System.out.println("Postfix notation: " + cad);
        System.out.println("Result: " + infix.evaluate(cad));
    }
    public String postfixConversion(String input) 
    {
        String postfix = "";
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) 
        {
            while (input.charAt(i) == ' ')
                ++i;
            if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))) 
            { 
                postfix += input.charAt(i);
                if (i + 1 < input.length() && !Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i + 1)))
                    postfix += ' ';
            }
            else if (getPrecedence(input.charAt(i)) != 0)
            {
                while ((!stack.isEmpty()) && (getPrecedence(stack.peek()) >= getPrecedence(input.charAt(i))) && (stack.peek() != '(')) 
                {
                    postfix += stack.pop();
                    postfix += ' ';
                }
                stack.push(input.charAt(i));
            }
            else if (input.charAt(i) == '(') 
                stack.push(input.charAt(i));
            else if (input.charAt(i) == ')') 
            {
                while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(')
                {
                    postfix += stack.peek();
                    stack.pop();
                }
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) 
        {
            postfix += stack.pop();
            postfix += ' ';
        }
        return postfix;
    }

    private double getPrecedence(char operator) 
    {
        double ret = 0;
        if (operator == '-' || operator == '+')
            ret = 1;
        else if (operator == '*' || operator == '/') 
            ret = 2;
        else if (operator == '^')
            ret = 3;
        return ret;
    }

    public Double evaluate(String postfix) 
    {
        Stack<Double> s = new Stack<Double>();
        char[] chars = postfix.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) 
        {
            char ch = chars[i];
            if (isOperatorPost(ch)) 
            {
                switch (ch) 
                {
                    case '+':
                        s.push(s.pop() + s.pop());
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        s.push(s.pop() * s.pop());
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        s.push(-s.pop() + s.pop());
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        s.push(1 / s.pop() * s.pop()); 
                        break;
                }
            } 
            else if(Character.isDigit(ch)) 
            {
                s.push(0.0);
                while (Character.isDigit(chars[i]))
                    s.push(10.0 * s.pop() + (chars[i++] - '0'));
            }
        }
        if (!s.isEmpty()) 
            return s.pop();
        else
            return 0.0;
    }
    private boolean isOperatorPost(char ch) 
    {
        return ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == '+' || ch == '-';
    }
}
```

but when changing:

```
String a = "(-342 / 2)";
```

output

```
Postfix notation: 342 2 /-
```

of course commenting on the line where I call to evaluate, because if I call it it gives me an error.

**It does not matter if I have to change to** **prefix notation** or **RPN** **or any other** but if I have to do it I need the code, that is the most important thing, it is fine if they try to explain me but the truth is I do not know if I can understand them, however if they tell me replace this with this and so on. I will understand better a thousand apologies and thanks to all

Comment: I use a regular expression to extract operands first.

Comment: @TheKNVB I already tried, investigated how to solve it with regular expression and it does not give

Comment: You should use the regular expression to extract operands with + or - sign first. Then the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer the following code for extract operands with + or - sign:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;  
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String expression = "(-342 / 2)";
        String realNoPattern="\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(e{1}[+-]?\\d+)?"; //real No. pattern string
        String patternString="[+-]{0,1}"+realNoPattern; //real no. with + or - sign
        
        Pattern  p=Pattern.compile(patternString);   
        Matcher m=p.matcher(expression);  
        while (m.find()){
            System.out.println(" Start : "+m.start()+", End : "+m.end()+" Pattern group : "+m.group());  
        }
    }
}
```

As you can make use of m.start and m.end to extract operator for further processing.